# Can a child theme based on Starker theme be released as free to use theme for public use?

Tags: theme-development, child-theme

I created a child theme named "Naksh" based on the "Starker" theme. Now I want to showcase it on WordPress. So, can I release it under GPL? Also is there any money I need to pay to Starker's creator for using his theme as a starting point?

Answer (score 2):

Just looked in the `_LINCESE.txt` file inside the theme folder. The theme is using the GPLv2 license and is also free available to everyone. Therefore you should not get any problems here.

Answer (score 0):

Point is that you currently can't upload child themes as it's (still) not supported by the official repo (for whatever reason). For the rest read @RomanWünsche Answer.

Comment: Hopefully one day. It's really outside our hands. The powers-that-be want to provide a different/better Child-Theme UX in the WP-Admin backend before we're allowed to approve them in the repository.

Comment: Sadly those "powers-that-be" are damn slow... :)

Comment: there are higher priorities for the WordPress project, and I understand that. Also, since we're talking about back-end changes to WordPress itself, any implementation will be tied to the WordPress release cycle and dates.